# Is it possible to delete from own table without tmp table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the following query:

```
DELETE FROM main_history WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT max(id) FROM main_history GROUP BY instance_id, xpath, new_value
)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
You can't specify target table 'main_history' for update in FROM clause
```

Is there a way to do this directly in mysql in a single query? I'm currently creating a tmp table like so:

```
INSERT INTO main_history_new (
    SELECT id, instance_id, territory_id, xpath, field, old_value, new_value, max(date)
    FROM main_history
    GROUP BY instance_id, xpath, new_value
)
```

Comment: Temporary table? MySQL's usually not bad, but sometimes it's downright ridiculous how limited it is.

Comment: have you tried something like:

`DELETE FROM (SELECT id FROM main_history WHERE....) as tmp_table`

Comment: @tadman it seems like this way worked: `DELETE FROM main_history WHERE id NOT IN (select id from (SELECT max(id) FROM main_history h GROUP BY instance_id, xpath, new_value) x)`